# Sonny Erickson c510 Backup

Tags: windows-7, backup, bluetooth, mobile-phone

In what folder does the computer save the file with the backed-up contacts from the phone? I have a sonny erickson c510 and windows 7

Comment: Would a sonny erickson phone contacts 'file type' search work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it in

C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\AppData\Local\Broadcom\Bluetooth Software\BluetoothDeviceBackups

file name was *.vcf